# Generating Nuget package on build does not include all dependencies

Tags: .net-core, nuget, nuget-package

The tree of my solution looks like :

Project A

- References Nuget Package "Some Package"

Project B

- References Project A

When building, project B produces a package, let's call it `PackageB`

In ProjectB.csproj I have used the following:

```
   <ProjectReference Include="ProjectA.csproj">
        <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>
    </ProjectReference>
```

Meaning `PackageB`, in addition to `ProjecdtB.dll`, includes `ProjectA.dll`

However it does not include "Some Package", so when I launch a client that references `PackageB`, I get a runtime error complaining that the dll contains in "Some Package" is missing.

How  can I make sure "Some Package" is added as a depencency of `PackageB`. I'd like to do this in csproj, without relying on a nuspec file. Is this possible ?

**[EDIT]**
In order to get ProjectA included in the PackageB, I also need to mention that I'm using the [Teronis.MSBuild.Packaging.ProjectBuildInPackage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Teronis.MSBuild.Packaging.ProjectBuildInPackage/).

Comment: The best way to realize it is to abandon using `Teronis` nuget package and remove the `<PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>` node. And it will make ProjectA as a nuget dependency for Project B. And you should also pack Project A as a nuget package. With all of them, when you install Package B, Package A will be installed at the same time and then `some packages` will be installed when package A is installed. And package B also can access transitive `some packages` during that process.

Comment: I wouldn't call this "the best way". This means every project should publish a nuget package, even those that should only be used as project reference within a solution and for which a package doesn't make sense. I finally came across this github issue and realized that this has been an ongoing unresolved problem for the last 4 years with no action taken by Microsoft. https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3891

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for using my package.

Let's first assume the following:

```
<!-- Project A -->
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="SomePackage" Version="*" />
</ItemGroup>

<!-- Project B -->
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="ProjectA" PrivateAssets="all">
  <!--<PackageReference Include="Teronis.MSBuild.Packaging.ProjectBuildInPackage" Version="0.1.7" />-->
</ItemGroup>
```

You are telling NuGet that you don't want to have Project A to be picked  up as NuGet-dependency. This is implicit, you don't have control about that. **The down-side is** the assmeblies of Project A, but not the assemblies of the packages of Project A, are not present in package of Project B.

By removing `PrivateAssets="all"` you disable the implicit behaviour of NuGet and the Project A will be picked up as NuGet dependency and EACH non-dependency package (also called transitive package).

Now let's asumme this:

```
<!-- Project A -->
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="SomePackage" Version="*" />
</ItemGroup>

<!-- Project B -->
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="ProjectA" PrivateAssets="all">
  <PackageReference Include="Teronis.MSBuild.Packaging.ProjectBuildInPackage" Version="0.1.7" />
</ItemGroup>
```

By having installed my package I assist in the implicit behaviour of NuGet: By not picking up Project A as NuGet-dependency copy over the direct assemblies produced by Project A to the bin-folder of Project B. **This has the following drawback:**

Because of the implicit behaviour and the usage of my package you have assemblies of Porject A in Project B that are in need of the assemblies provided by packages (in your example "Some Package") you referenced in Project A. So a workaround is to add the packages from Project A in Project B explicitly as shown here:

```
<!-- Project A -->
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="SomePackage" Version="*" />
</ItemGroup>

<!-- Project B -->
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="ProjectA" PrivateAssets="all">
  <PackageReference Include="Teronis.MSBuild.Packaging.ProjectBuildInPackage" Version="0.1.7" />
  <!-- Use the SAME version like in Project A. -->
  <PackageReference Include="SomePackage" Version="*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

This should solve your problem. Please provide feedback when it does NOT work.

Answer (score 0):

In the [PackageReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets) documentation, `PrivateAssets` is described as:

> These assets will be consumed but won't flow to the parent project
> Meaning the dependencies of Project A won't be copied over in Package B.

If you remove the `PrivateAssets` node, it should flow the dependencies properly.

Comment: If I remove PrivateAssets, the referenced project ProjectA does not event get included any more in the PackagB

Comment: That's odd. Are you using `IncludeAssets` or `ExcludeAssets` anywhere?

Comment: No I don't use these. I've updated my post because I forgot to mention I'm using the teronis package in order to include project reference in the generated package